# Why does spring initializr make a project inheriting from spring-boot-starter-parent instead of using spring-boot-dependencies

Tags: spring-boot, maven, spring-initializr

When a project is created with spring initalizr then `pom.xml` inherits from `spring-boot-starter-parent`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
```

This seems to be less flexible comparing to specifying `spring-boot-dependencies` in `<dependencyManagement/>`, for if we need to use the generated structure as a child module of multi-module project, or use company-wide parent we need to move BOM into mentioned section:

```xml
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Is there any specific reason for usage of `spring-boot-starter-parent` as parent instead of declaring `<dependencyManagement/>` section immediately at creation time?

Comment: The spring boot starter parent defines all needed configuration for the maven plugins (versions, configuration etc.) which the spring-boot-dependencies does not... and as you already realized the spring-boot-dependencies is the right way to handle that in a mutli module setup or with a different partent than the spring-boot-starter-parent...

Comment: I understand, that lots of settings come along with spring-boot-starter-parent. The question is why not to include them into generated POM explicitly keeping spring-boot-dependencies in dependencyManagement section? I guess most of the projects generated via spring initializr eventually become submodules. Event if we are talking about beginners inheriting the settings from parent pom seems to be deleterious for them due to magic-comes-out-of-the-box approach

Comment: Because that is not conveninient and would make the resulting pom more unreadable..and I do not agree because the majority of the SB project are kept single module project...

Answer (score 1):

Someones have voted to close the Q, insisting it is opinion based, however, it is not.

The existence of plugin configurations (*BTW, at first glance the purpose of those configurations was to fix some "glitches" of maven plugins, however, some of those configurations are not required anymore, for example: https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/pull/1501*) is not the only difference between:

```xml
<parent>
 <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
 <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
 <version>3.1.3</version>
 <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

and

```xml
<dependencyManagement>
 <dependencies>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
   <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
   <type>pom</type>
   <scope>import</scope>
  </dependency>
 </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

In the first case, maven project inherits `dependencyManagement` via parent-child relationship and so, since `spring-boot` team defines dependency versions via `properties` section, the child project may override dependency versions via `properties` section as well, e.g. if our goal is to change the version of `spring-framework` without changing the version of `spring-boot` we may define something like:

```xml
<properties>
 <spring-framework.version>6.0.15</spring-framework.version>
</properties>
```

which, obviously won't work in case of second configuration - there maven just imports `dependencyManagement` section from **independent** BoM.

That is not clear what approach is "more flexible" (we prefer to stay clear of both), however they are different from dependency management perspective as well.

Comment: Are there any additional autoconfigurations applied when `spring-boot-starter-parent` is used in comparison to the second approach?

Comment: The autoconfigurations are applied only when they are in runtime classpath and the classpath is defined by `<dependency/>` section AFAIK. So if the `<dependency/>` is left intact there shouldn't be any additional autoconfiguration.